# Is there any automatic differentiation package?

Tags: numerics, calculus-and-analysis

I'm wondering if an automatic differentiation package exists for *Mathematica*.
[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) is what I mean by automatic differentiation.

Comment: I don't know; but it's interesting to note that in Mathematica the distinction between a program and a symbolic expression is blurred.  Many of the simple cases will just work with `D`/`Derivative`.  It will be interesting to see some rudimentary implementations.  See also http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Feb/msg00381.html

Comment: To add to what Szabolcs said, for pure Mathematica expressions, symbolic differentiation is pretty much a generalization of automatic differentiation. I would guess that for these expressions, true automatic differentiation may not be any more efficient than using `D`.

Comment: In the link you provided are listed different packages, some of which are written in languages that can communicate with Mathematica. See http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AutomaticDifferentiation/ and http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/acegen/

Comment: This is a very relevant question. It is not fun to give optimization routines like FindMinimum huge expressions generated by running some algorithm so that it can do symbolic differentiation on them. Falling back to numerical finite differences seems like a waste compared to the automatic differentation idea (see e.g. https://justindomke.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/automatic-differentiation-the-most-criminally-underused-tool-in-the-potential-machine-learning-toolbox/ ).

Answer (score 19):

For anyone still interested in this: I'm working on an implementation of dual numbers for Mathematica which should allow you to calculate automatic derivatives of (hopefully) many programs.

Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/ssmit1986/DualNumbers).

Here's a quick example of how to obtain the derivative of a programmatic function with a `While` loop (adapted from the documentation). It's a fixed point algorithm to solve an equation:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, x0 : _?NumericQ : 1.0] := 
 Module[{ x = x0, y, i = 0},
  While[(y = Cos[a x]) != x,
   x = y;
   i++
   ];
  x
 ];
```

It doesn't have a symbolic derivative:

```
Derivative[1] @ f
(* Derivative[1][f] *)
```

You can find the derivative of its first argument simply by passing a `Dual` with non-standard part equal to 1:

```
<<DualNumbers`
f[1.]
f[Dual[1., 1.]]
(* 0.739085 *)
(* Dual[0.739085, -0.297474] *)
```

The first argument of `Dual` is the function value and the second argument is the derivative at that point. Let's convince ourselves that this derivative is correct:

```
With[{h = 0.001, a = 1.0},
 (f[a + h] - f[a - h])/(2 h)
 ]
(* -0.297474 *)
```

Let's also check the derivative of the second argument:

```
f[1., Dual[1., 1.]]
(* Dual[0.739085, 1.86543*10^-14] *)
```

The derivative of the second argument is pretty much zero. This makes sense, of course, since small variations in the initial value in the fixed point search shouldn't influence the result.

Comment: I'm intrigued!  Could you add an example or two here of using it for automatic differentiation?

Comment: @ChrisK I'm still working on documentation and examples, but this should give you an idea. If you have any ideas to try it out on, please let me know :).

Comment: For neural networks, I always wanted something that could derive backward AD in matrix or einsum notation. For instance results in https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/NA-08-01.pdf . When I was on tensorflow team, we derived them by hand, basically through "guess-and-check"

Comment: BTW, if you make it work for einsum notation, @Carl Woll's `TensorReduce` automatically translates it into matrix notation -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207336/generating-an-efficient-way-to-compute-einsum

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov That's a good idea, but I've not used that package before so it might be a while for me to look into this. Feel free to make a pull request to my repo if you have any ideas about this.

Comment: Thanks for the examples.  Now I need to come up with some application for myself ;)

Comment: For anyone interested in the question by @YaroslavBulatov : see the discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/ssmit1986/DualNumbers/issues/1

Comment: @SjoerdSmit This is very cool. Thanks! This is Forward mode AD, right? are you planning to implement reverse mode AD too?

Comment: @psimeson Correct, this is for forwards AD. Reverse AD will be a lot more work to implement and I don't plan on starting that any time soon (if at all), given how much time I can spend on these sorts of hobby projects right now (i.e., not a lot). I also think that reverse mode AD should probably be implemented at a deeper level in the kernel code and that's not really my expertise. I'm kinda hoping that the idea might be picked up in Champaign for a future release of WL.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I hope Wolfram picks up the AD idea and implements it at the core level. Julia language seems to be doing so.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  can we find  an example for Derivatives of tensor valued functions of second-order tensors using this package?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM If you post an issue in my GH repository with some examples of what you want to do (i.e, desired input and output), I'll take a look when I have time.

Comment: Dual numbers can be implemented by adding just one line to a notebook: `$Pre=MatrixFunction[Function[ε,#],{{0,0},{1,0}}]/.{{a_,b_},{0,a_}}->a+ε b /.{{a_,0},{b_,a_}}->a+ε b&;` https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241593/651

Answer (score 9):

Try [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AutomaticDifferentiation/). It may not be exactly what your looking for, but it also may give you a good starting point.