# How to implement dual numbers in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, algebraic-manipulation

I wonder how can I implement [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) in *Mathematica*, so that all functions work well with them (as with complex numbers).

Particularly, for each function $f$, $f(\varepsilon)=f^\prime(0)\varepsilon$

Comment: if you use the matrix representation and matrix operations (multiplication etc) then the nilpotency of $\sigma^\dagger$ takes care of multiplication. You probably would need to define the $f(\epsilon)=f'(0)\epsilon$ relation by hand, though.

Comment: This demo is about dual numbers and automatic differentiation http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AutomaticDifferentiation/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer combines the best traits ftom my previous answer and the answer by Daniel Lichyblau.

The following line adds the symbol for dual unity the same way as if it was a pre-defined constant like imaginary unit:

`$Post=(#/.ε->0)+ε(D[#, ε]/.ε->0)&`

Answer (score 31):

Here's a tiny piece of advice I follow: any time I want to implement a new, exotic number system in *Mathematica*, the first thing I do is to look within the implementation of the `` Quaternions` `` package, and try to adapt/emulate the constructions in the package to the number system I am trying to implement.

Having said this, here's a bunch of rules for doing basic arithmetic with dual numbers, as well as a general rule for evaluating functions with dual number arguments (notice the heavy use of `TagSetDelayed[]` so that the rules are associated with `Dual[]` and not the arithmetic/transcendental functions):

```
ScalarQ[c_] := ! MatchQ[Head[c], Dual] && NumericQ[c]

DualEpsilon = Dual[0, 1];
Dual /: Dual[a_, 0] := a;
Dual /: c_?ScalarQ + Dual[a_, b_] := Dual[c + a, b];
Dual /: Dual[a_, b_] + Dual[c_, d_] := Dual[a + c, b + d];
Dual /: c_?ScalarQ*Dual[a_, b_] := Dual[c a, c b];
Dual /: Dual[a_, b_]*Dual[c_, d_] := Dual[a c, b c + a d];
Dual /: Power[d_Dual, n_Integer?Positive] := 
        Fold[(If[#2 == 1, d, 1] #1) #1 &, d, Rest[IntegerDigits[n, 2]]];
Dual /: Power[Dual[a_, b_], -1] := Dual[1/a, -b/a^2];
Dual /: Power[d_Dual, n_Integer?Negative] := 1/Power[d, -n];
Dual /: Power[Dual[a_, b_], x_?ScalarQ] := Dual[a^x, b x a^(x - 1)];
Dual /: Abs[Dual[a_, b_]] := Dual[Abs[a], b Sign[a]];
Dual /: Sign[Dual[a_, b_]] := Sign[a];
Dual /: f_[d__Dual] /; MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction] := With[{args = {d}}, 
           Dual[f @@ args[[All, 1]],
                (Derivative[##][f] @@ args[[All, 1]]) & @@@
                IdentityMatrix[Length[args]].args[[All, 2]]]]
```

Samples:

```
Dual[a, b]/Dual[c, d]
   Dual[a/c, b/c - (a d)/c^2]

Dual[a, b]^(2/3)
   Dual[a^(2/3), (2 b)/(3 a^(1/3))]

Exp[Dual[a, b]]
   Dual[E^a, b E^a]

3 Dual[a, b]^2 - 2 Dual[a, b]
   Dual[-2 a + 3 a^2, -2 b + 6 a b]

Dual[a, b]^Dual[c, d]
   Dual[a^c, a^(-1 + c) b c + a^c d Log[a]]
```

The last rule, while fairly general, will give erroneous results for functions like `Floor[]`, `Mod[]`, etc. Adding the rules needed for proper evaluation of those, as well as adding formatting rules (such that e.g. `Dual[a, b]` prints as $a+b\varepsilon$ in `StandardForm`) is left as an exercise.

Comment: Why the double test using ScalarQ in the line `Dual /: c_?ScalarQ * Dual[a_, b_] /; ScalarQ[c] := Dual[c a, c b];` ?

Comment: @Sjoerd, that's an error, whoops. I'll edit later. Thanks!

Comment: I took this post as the starting point for my own package for implementing dual numbers: https://github.com/ssmit1986/DualNumbers

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, looks like an interesting package! I'm glad you were able to use this.

Answer (score 19):

If you use the matrix representation, addition and multiplication works by default, but you need to use matrix multiplication and not just space (which is element-wise multiplication), for instance `f[a_,b_]:=a.b+b.b` would for instance work exactly like you would expect if a and b where dual numbers.

If you just want to have the rule enforce that you mention, you could just write that rule out:

```
 dualE /: f_[dualE] := f'[0] dualE
```

You can add other rules to make your other algebra work out aswell for intance for multiplication:

```
 dualE /: Power[dualE, 2] := 0
 (a + dualE b) (c + dualE d) // Expand // Collect[#, dualE] &
```

**Update**

If you want the full function application rule, then there is a problem with just defining it, lets assume you wanted to write down: `f_[a+b dualE]:=f[a]+b f'[0] dualE` if we expand this into the expression form it reads: `f_[Plus[a,Times[b,dualE]]]:=...` now such a definition can't have it's pattern attached to dualE, since it doesn't appear in the top level. What you would then need is to create a symbol that represents a dual number with both parts included, as Sasha suggested in a comment. Here is an example writing up rules for `Times` and `Plus`:

```
 dualE:=dualNumber[0,1];
 Times[dualNumber[r1_,d1_],dualNumber[r2_,d2_]] ^:= dualNumber[r1 r2,d2 r1+d1 r2]
 Times[dualNumber[r_,d_],n_] ^:= dualNumber[n r,n d]
 Plus[dualNumber[r_,d_],n_] ^:= dualNumber[r+n,d]
```

Then you can write the definition for function application with respect to `dualNumber`

```
 dualNumber /: f_[dualNumber[r_, d_]] := f[r] + d f'[r] dualE
```

And if you would like the numbers to be printed like `2+ 3 duelE` rather then as `dualNumber[2,3]`. Then you can define a `MakeBoxes` rule for it.

```
 MakeBoxes[dualNumber[a_, d_], StandardForm] ^:= 
     RowBox[{MakeBoxes@a, "+", MakeBoxes@(Times[d, "dualE"])}]
```

Now then this works together to allow:

```
 Sin[(4 + dualE) (2 + 3 dualE)]
```

> ```
> Sin[8] + dualE 14
> ```

```
 Sin[(a + b dualE) (c + d dualE)]
```

> Sin[a c] + (b c + a d) dualE

Edited to correct error caught by Rahul Narain, also to improve incorrect output formating in symbolic expressions.

Comment: Thank you! This is very informative! I will try it.

Comment: Unfortunately even after your first rule it cannot find Cos[1+dualE] although Cos[dualE] finds well.

Comment: @Anixx That is because the full rule of a function application on a dual number isn't implemented, only the dualE part. If you want the full rule `f[a+b dualE]`, you would have to implement it. Then however it gets problematic. Note my update to the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that should be `dualNumber /: f_[dualNumber[r_, d_]] := f[r] + f'[r] d dualE` instead, to match the intuition of $\varepsilon$ being an infinitesimal.

Comment: @Rahul Narain indeed this is probably a typo

Comment: If I replace numbers under sine with letters, this does not expand :-(

Comment: @Anixx It should work now, the typesetting function was only inteded for numerical results.

Comment: I suppose modifying the formatting rule to handle, say, `dualNumber[0, -1]` properly will take a bit more effort...

Comment: @J. M. indeed, if d starts with "-", then we get "+ -"

Comment: @J.M. I wouldn't say it's handling it improperly, it could have nicer formatting, but the output is syntactically correct and can be provided as input. But sure, it could go further in looking pretty.

Comment: Still f[r] + d f'[0] dualE is wrong. It should be f[r] + d f'[r] dualE

Comment: Perhaps you should also update the example outputs at the end.

Comment: By the way, I can only get your `Times` and `Plus` rules to work by prefixing them with `dualNumber /:` like the rule for function application. Am I doing something wrong? (I'm on Mathematica 8.)

Comment: @RahulNarain You can either bind it to dualNumber or unprotect Times and Plus, but the latter is not advisable, so either prefix `dualNumber/:` or use  `^:=` when setting.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly a function that applies functions, by expanding to first order in the `dualE` part.

```
dualfunc[func_, d_] := Normal[Series[func[d], {dualE, 0, 1}]]

dualfunc[Sin, 3 + dualE]

(* dualE Cos[3] + Sin[3] *)
```

This has the inconvenience of being awkward, since it would need to be used with basic arithmetic (but as noted in other responses, `UpValues` on `dualE` could perhaps address this). An advantage is that it should work in a reasonably consistent manner, and (I hope) not require much beyond what I did here; might need some special fault-handling if you encounter the likes of `1/dualE`.

Comment: This is a good idea. Possibly one can combine it with my method so to get expressions evaluated inline.

Comment: Ok, so this works: $Post=Normal[Series[#, {dualE, 0, 1}]]&;

Answer (score 8):

Well,

```
$Post = MatrixFunction[
      Function[ε, #], {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}] /. {{a_, 
        b_}, {0, a_}} -> 
      a + ε b /. {{a_, 0}, {b_, a_}} -> 
     a + ε b &;
```

After this one can use any formulas with dual unity `ε`:

```
 I^ε

 Out= 1 + (I ε Pi)/2
```

Comment: Back on it after 9 years? That’s dedication!

Comment: @ChrisK Number duels in the US became illegal in 2013 and only recently were legalized again. They are, however, tightly regulated and only allowed in some states.

Comment: How do you extract the second term that multiplies the epsilon ?  The automatic differentiation property does not seem to allow `Coefficient`, `D` or `Cases` to obtain the the second term that multiplies the epsilon.

Answer (score 7):

You can map any dual number $a + b \epsilon$ into a $2 \times 2$ matrix:
$$
    a + b \epsilon \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr 0 & a \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: And so? How to make Mathematica to do operations with these matrices as with dual numbers?

Comment: It depends on what you would like to do. If basic arithmetic is your primary goal, then it would be appropriate to define `DualNumber[a,b]` object and overload `Times`, `Plus` and `Power` to work on them. If you need also elementary functions to work on it, then going the route with matrices might be less work.

Comment: I want all functions to work with them like with complex numbers. Particularly, I want any function f applied to $\epsilon$ to be evaluated as $f'[0]\epsilon$