# New data type, interval, and overloading operators (+,-,*,/)

Tags: symbolic, algebra

How can I create a new data type, interval, with different behavior than the built-in one. I want to write `[a, b]` and perform operator overloading, as in C ++? (I have to use a different algebra than that of the built-in `Interval`)

Example of an operation (same as dafault, but I would like to implement it):

```
[a, b] + [c, d] = [a + c, b + d];
```

I am using *Mathematica* V.8

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13926)…

Comment: J.M. I can not understand the topic covered in this post, so it's hard to understand :(

Comment: The point of that post is that you define how the arithmetic operations affect your objects with `TagSetDelayed[]`. For instance: `myInterval /: myInterval[a_, b_] + myInterval[c_, d_] := myInterval[a + c, b + d]`.

Comment: J.M. It seems to be interesting , at this point how can I declare a variable with this new type and algebra ?
myInterval[2,3]+myInterval[4,5] => myInterval[6,8] Ok!

but if the different fossere variables? It is also possible to define some properties, for example the associative?
I'm sorry but I'm trying to understand how it works.
Thanks.

Comment: `Plus[]` already has the `Flat` (associative) attribute, so it should already work with the definition I gave.

Comment: J.M. I'm beginning to understand how it works , do some testing , thank you ;)

Comment: Ok J.M.  I will let you know,thank you ;)

Comment: J.M. excuse me, if I want to define a type of function GetLower[ IIntervalVAR [a, b ] ]- > how can I do ?

Comment: @plus91 What should your `GetLower[Interval[a, b]]` function return? $a$? or the minimum value between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @MarcoB the function should return the value of " a "

Comment: @MarcoB grazie ;)

Comment: Search for `gplus` in the tutorial [Associating Definitions with Different Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in comments, [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) (i.e. the combination of `/:` and `:=`) allows you to impose your desired behavior upon symbols in particular situations. For instance, below I define the additive property you asked for. You can also define the behavior of built in functions when used in combination with your `myInterval` object; for example "teach" the built-in `Min` and `Max` what to return when dealing with one such object.

```
ClearAll[myInterval]

(* If the bounds are explicitly numerical, reorder them with the lower bound first *)
myInterval[a_, b_] /; a > b := myInterval[b, a]

(* Define the sum property *)
myInterval /: myInterval[a_, b_] + myInterval[c_, d_] := myInterval[a + c, b + d]

(* Define the behavior of Max, Min, MinMax with your myInterval object *)
myInterval /: Min[myInterval[a_, b_]] := a
myInterval /: Max[myInterval[a_, b_]] := b
myInterval /: MinMax[myInterval[a_, b_]] := MinMax[{a, b}]
```

You can now evaluate the following expressions:

```
myInterval[3, 5] + myInterval[5, 6] (* myInterval[8, 11] *)

myInterval[5, 4]                    (* myInterval[4, 5] *)

Min @ myInterval[5, 4]              (* 4 *)
Max @ myInterval[5, 4]              (* 5 *)

MinMax @ myInterval[5, 4]           (* {4, 5} *)
```

Comment: I would like to define the following function F [ a_ +b_ * Subscript[e, j_], if F  is called F[a_] -> myInterval[a,a,0] else if it is called F[a+b*Subscript[e, j]]->myInterval[a-b,a+b,j],
I tried so few but nothing.
any idea?

Thanks in Advice

Comment: It would seem that the following should work: `F[a_] := myInterval[a, a, 0]; F[a_ + b_*Subscript[e_, j_]] := myInterval[a - b, a + b, j]`. If it doesn't, I'd suggest that you post a different question so you can explain your requirements more fully and perhaps add some examples as well.