# How implement Dual Quaternion algebra in Mathematica?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, quaternions

How can we manipulate and operate with dual quaternionic variables in Mathematica? Since a dual quaternion can be expressed like this

$\hat q = a + \epsilon b $

where $a,b \in \mathbb{H}$, or writing in the explicit form

$\hat q = a_0+a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k + \epsilon (b_0+b_1 i + b_2 j + b_3 k ) $

It's possible to utilize the Quaternion package with the definition of dual unit, with $\epsilon^2=0$

```
\[\Epsilon] /: Power[\[Epsilon], n_] := 0 /; n >= 2
```

to acomplish this?

Comment: You can always [express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion#Matrix_form_of_dual_quaternion_multiplication) the dual quaternion product as a $8\times8$ matrix product.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code:

`Post=(#/.ε->0)+ε(D[#, ε]/.ε->0)&`

Then use quaternions and $ε$.

Comment: Reference to  the other answers implementing dual numbers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13912/86543)

Answer (score 1):

While the answer from Anixx is good for dual number and some basic operations from Quaternions package, you may need to implement the Norm[] and Normalize[] if you want to work with unit dual quaternion. The block code below is my implementation for both functions (developed from Anixx answer and ashen answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174899/properly-normalizing-a-dual-quaternion)):

```
Needs["Quaternions`"]
DQ={(#/.de->0)+de(D[#, de]/.de->0)}&;
a = DQ[Quaternion[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]+de Quaternion[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]]
MyNorm= Norm[#] /. de -> 0 &;
InternalDotDQ=(List @@(# /. de->0)[[1]]).(List @@ Coefficient[#,de][[1]]) &;
MyNormalize=(# /. de->0)/ MyNorm[#] + de (Coefficient[#,de] / MyNorm[#]  - (# /. de->0) * ((List @@  (# /. de->0)[[1]]).(List @@ Coefficient[#,de][[1]]))/ (MyNorm[#] ^3))&;
b = MyNormalize[a]
InternalDotDQ[b]
MyNorm[b]
```

Note that unit dual quaternion require the internal dot product = 0 and the new norm = 1, `List @@` is Apply List (I need this to perform dot product), `(# /. de->0)[[1]]` will return the real part, and `Coefficient[#,de][[1]]` returns the dual part.