# How would one add Hyperreals as a new type to Mathematica?

Tags: number-representation, custom-notation

[Hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) are an extension to the real numbers; they formalise the concepts of infinities and infinitestimals as numbers, rather than the named limit points outside of the system of reals and form the basis of non-standard analysis.

Hyperreals are analogous to Complex numbers in that a hyperreal can be be expressed as a pair {r, h} where r is the Real part and h the hyperreal part, e.g. {1, $\epsilon$}, {1, $\omega$}, {1, 2 $\omega$}, {1, $\omega^2$}, etc.

A search suggests that there is currently no support for hyperreals in Mathematica, either from Wolfram directly or as a user demonstration or other package.

How would one go about defining the hyperreals, arithmetic operations, relations (<, >, =, !=, etc.), etc. so that they could be handled like any other number kind, and in particular sorted, so that given the list $\{1, \epsilon, \epsilon^2, \omega -1, \omega -2 \}$ the result of sorting it would be $\{0, \epsilon^2, \epsilon, 1, \omega -2, \omega -1 \}$?

I believe that any function of the reals can be extended straightforwardly to the hyperreals (in which context Łoś' theorem and the transfer principle are referenced, but I am not mathematically sophisticated enough to assert their relevance).

To be specific:

- How would one define the symbols $\epsilon$ and $\omega$?
- How would one extend the definitions of basic arithmetic functions (+, -, *, /, ^) to handle hyperreals?
- How would one extend magnitude and equality relationships accordingly?

(I would ask whether, alternatively, the scope of application is so great, e.g. as arguments in exponentials, polynomials, calculus, etc. that only Wolfram could do such a thing - but that would be largely a matter of option, so I won't.)

**Update** I have now looked at both B3m2a1 and Jason B's approaches to custom objects in [custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutoria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutorial) and whilst I am perhaps now infinitesimally wiser I am also infinitely sadder at the impenetrability of Mathematica for tasks other than simple arithmetic, algebra, solving, graphical, etc. tasks. I thought I was making progress but now realise I have only managed to walk from the car park to the base of what turns out to be El Capitan. I've seen - nay, studied! - the examples and I *still* have no confidence about how I might proceed.

**Update 2 re basic quantities, principles in response to comments etc.**

Re @DanielLicthblau & @yawnoc's point about preferred/basic quantities: as soon as I started working on it myself I realised the same and adopted a principled position.

Calling the parts of the hyperreal the Standard and NonStandard parts: in validation etc. the Standard part may not contain any infinit* quantity, and - initially at least - I decided that the NonStandard part could be a polynomial in $\epsilon$ and/or $\omega$ without purely numeric terms, but given $\epsilon = 1/\omega$, monomials with -ve exponents should be re-expressed in terms of the other quanity, hence (code fragments)

```
ClearAll[\[Epsilon], \[Omega]];
ClearAll[HyperrealSimplify, HyperrealSymbolQ, HyperrealPolynomialQ, HyperrealValidQ];
HyperrealSymbolQ[sym_]:= MemberQ[{\[Epsilon], \[Omega]}, sym];
HyperrealPolynomialQ[expr_]:= (PolynomialQ[expr, \[Epsilon]] || PolynomialQ[expr, \[Omega]]) && !MemberQ[MonomialList[expr], _?NumberQ];
HyperrealSimplify[expr_]:= (expr /. Power[\[Epsilon], p_?Negative] -> Power[\[Omega], Abs@p]) /. Power[\[Omega], p_?Negative] -> Power[\[Epsilon], Abs@p];
HyperrealValidQ[pair_List]:=!HyperrealPolynomialQ[pair[[1]]] && HyperrealPolynomialQ[pair[[2]]]; (* 1st item must not involve Hyperreal symbols and 2nd item must - without isolated non-hyperreals, e.g. numbers*)
```

(I would also include this in the simplification process...

```
Block[{\[Epsilon], \[Omega]}, Simplify[hrs, TransformationFunctions -> {\[Epsilon] := 1/\[Omega]}]]
```

)

Symbols in the NonStandard part would be dealt with at the time of evaluation and re-validation of the Hyperreal object.

The hyperreals were already shaping up like Complex, & @SjoerdSmit's package would be an excellent place to start... if I were better at MMA.

Comment: This is somewhat open-ended, which is more due to the nature of the topic than the wording of the question. What beyond arithmetic is in scope? Does one "basic" infinitesimal (and its powers) suffice? Is omega going to be 1/epsilon (sorry, I still don't know how to format those as Greek letters for MSE). Even with answers to these I'm not sure what would be a good way to attack it. Triples of the form {infinite,finite,infinitesimal}? Maybe.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - try switching your keyboard settings to a Greek keyboard when entering the Greek letters. You could also show the keyboard viewer for reference.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. I think I now have this working one one laptop. No guarantees for other machines I use though (different OS/ΟΣ).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I would have to agree that the ramifications are potentially deep, but the limited scope would be enough for me for now; and yes I do believe that $1/\epsilon = \omega$. For example; I would define a hyperreal like Complex in parts, but don't know how to create a new Head like this, or overload the operators (though I can see what the overloading content would probably look like) - I suspect Upvalues are involved... but up, down, (own, sub) values are things I have not previously grappled with. (PS: I use inline TeX like this: \$ 1/\epsilon = \omega \$)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau (continued) and relationships I can also see how to approach by substituting specific Real values (<1, >1) for evaluation, but again... overloading.

Comment: My maths are way to rusty for dealing with hyperreals, but I recently made a package for doing computations with dual numbers, which are a bit like baby's first hyperreals. Take a look at my [code on Github](https://github.com/ssmit1986/DualNumbers) to get a feel for how to approach something like this. Feel free to contact me on GH for concrete questions about it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm pretty sure there are no "preferred" or "basic" infinitesimal/infinite quantities in the hyperreal system. John Conway's [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) seem to have a "basic" $\epsilon$ and $\omega$, but I don't know enough about surreal numbers to elaborate further. [Smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis) has $\epsilon^2 = 0$ (with nothing "special" about $\epsilon$) and no infinite quantities.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit That's interesting & useful work - and so was the inspiring Q: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/how-to-implement-dual-numbers-in-mathematica. I was unaware of Dual numbers. I do think I seriously misunderestimated (to coin a word ;) the magnitude of the task in MMA - mathematical niceties aside!

Comment: One thing I can recommend is that for basic arithmetic, I'd just create a head Hyperreals[] that takes one or more arguments e.g. as triples, and an operation e.g. "Times", and returns a triple representing a Hyperreal. See the resource function [EisensteinIntegers](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EisensteinIntegers/) for similar treatment.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That could work... let me look. Thanks.