# How to define a new algebra using TagSet?

Tags: algebra, quaternions

For example, I would like to define the algebra of quaternions. I coded something like

```
Unprotect[i, j, k]; ClearAll[i, j, k]
i /: i ** i := -1;
i /: i ** j := k;
i /: j ** i = -k;
i /: i ** k := -j;
i /: k ** i = j;
j /: j ** j := -1;
j /: j ** k := i;
j /: k ** j := -i;
k /: k ** k := -1;
Protect[i, j, k];
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
  Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &];
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
  Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]];
ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a];
QQ = Collect[ExpandNCM[#], {i, j, k}] &;
```

However, I got two different results when calculating

```
(a i + b j + c k) ** (d i + e j + f k) // QQ
(a i + b j + c k) ** (l i + m j + n k) // QQ
```

The first one gave the expected result

```
k (a e-b d)+j (c d-a f)-a d+i (b f-c e)-b e-c f
```

while the second one gave a weird answer

```
i (a i**l+b j**l+c k**l)+j (a i**m+b j**m+c k**m)+k (a i**n+b j**n+c k**n)
```

I hope the NonCommutativeMultiply `**` only operates on those `i,j,k`. I don't know where the problem is.

I also want to know if there is a handy way to define a new algebra?

**Updated**

Now the algebra has been set up for `+, *, **` but not `Power`.

Here is the code

```
Unprotect[i, j, k]; ClearAll[i, j, k, ijkQ, ExpandNCM, Qconj, Qreal, \
Qimag]
i /: i ** i := -1;
i /: i*i := -1;
i /: i ** j := k;
i /: j ** i = -k;
i /: i ** k := -j;
i /: k ** i = j;
j /: j ** j := -1;
j /: j*j := -1;
j /: j ** k := i;
j /: k ** j := -i;
k /: k ** k := -1;
k /: k*k := -1;

i /: Qconj[i] := -i;
j /: Qconj[j] := -j;
k /: Qconj[k] := -k;
Protect[i, j, k];

Qconj[a_: 0] := a /; FreeQ[a, i | j | k];
Qconj[(b_: 1)*(q : i | j | k)] := b*Qconj[q] /; FreeQ[b, i | j | k];
Qconj[a_ + b_] := Qconj[a] + Qconj[b];

Qreal := Select[# + i, (FreeQ[#, i | j | k] &)] &;
Subscript[Qimag, x_] := ({0}~Join~
     Cases[{#}, (a : (_?(FreeQ[#, i | j | k] &)) : 1)*x :> a, 
      Infinity])[[-1]] &

ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
  Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &];

ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, 
    b_?(FreeQ[#, i | j | k] &)*(q : i | j | k), c___]] := 
  b*ExpandNCM[h[a, q, c]];
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, 
    b_?(FreeQ[#, i | j | k] &), c___]] := b*ExpandNCM[h[a, c]];

ExpandNCM[(h : (Times | Plus))[a___, b_NonCommutativeMultiply, 
    c___]] := h[a, c, ExpandNCM[b]];
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a_: 1]] := a;

ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a];

QQ = Collect[ExpandNCM[#], {i, j, k}] &;
```

Now the problem is how to set up the rules for `Power`, such as `Exp[]` , `Log[]` and `Power[]`. For example, I want to define `Power[q,n]` as `q**q** ... **q` and then use it to define `Exp[q]`. How should I do?

Note that the algebra of quaternions here is just an example. What I want is to define the rules for the algebra and let the Mathematica do the calculations. These rules will be changed.

Comment: Rather than try to define the algebra directly on the special symbols i,j,k, I'd suggest you define a special wrapper `Quaternion[...]`. this would be analogous to `Complex[...]` (Note that `FullForm[a+b I]` is `Plus[a, Times[Complex[0, 1], b]]` and just `FullForm[I]` is `Complex[0,1]`. Then you would define your operations for pairs of Quaternion elements. For your special symbols, you could define `i = Quaternion[0,1,0,0]` and similarly for j and k.

Comment: I should add that you can then use `Format` to provide a friendly display form for your `Quaternion[...]`s.

Comment: Hi, there is an analogous question and answer with the algebra of dual numbers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13912/86543). The first answer there, at the present time, uses the quaternion package to make an algebra using TagSet

Comment: Sweet! The Quaternions package should supercede my answer. It's nice, though, to see that I went down a similar path.

Comment: Just adding a point on what @lericr mentioned, `FullForm[a+b I]` is `Plus[a, Times[Complex[0, 1], b]]` and not `Complex[a,b]` because `a` and `b` could be complex themselves. `FullForm[1+2*I]` is `Complex[1,2]` as expected because 1 and 2 are real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer for the "I don't know where the problem is" question.
The problem is this definition

```
ExpandNCM[(h:NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___,b_Times,c___]]:=Most[b]*ExpandNCM[h[a,Last[b],c]];
```

and more precisely the pattern `b`. To understand the problem, enter

```
d*i
(* d * i *)

m*i
(* i * m *)
```

In the second case, `Times` has reordered the variables and put `i` before `m`. This is because `Times` is `Orderless` and `i` comes before `m` in the canonical order.

Therefore, if the `b_Times` in the definition above is matched with `m*i` then

```
Most[b] == i
Last[b] == m
```

and the `i` is moved out of the NoncommutativeMultiply.

One possible fix is to replace the definition above by (but please clear old definitions before doing this):

```
ExpandNCM[(h:NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___,b_*(q:i|j|k),c___]]:=b*ExpandNCM[h[a,q,c]];
```

Now

```
(a i+b j+c k)**(l i+m j+n k) // QQ
(* -a l-b m+k (-b l+a m)-c n+j (c l-a n)+i (-c m+b n) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Just found out that there's a Quaternions package: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Quaternions/tutorial/Quaternions.html

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here's a start:

```
(* some basic helpers *)
Quaternion[a_] := Quaternion[a, 0, 0, 0];
Quaternion[a_, b_] := Quaternion[a, b, 0, 0];
Quaternion[a_, b_, c_] := Quaternion[a, b, c, 0];
QI = Quaternion[0, 1];
QJ = Quaternion[0, 0, 1];
QK = Quaternion[0, 0, 0, 1];
```

Now a bit of meat:

```
Quaternion /: 
  NonCommutativeMultiply[Quaternion[a1_, b1_, c1_, d1_], Quaternion[a2_, b2_, c2_, d2_]] :=
    Quaternion[
      a1 a2 - b1 b2 - c1 c2 - d1 d2, 
      a1 b2 + b1 a2 + c1 d2 - d1 c2, 
      a1 c2 - b1 d2 + c1 a2 + d1 b2, 
      a1 d2 + b1 c2 - c1 b2 + d1 a2]
```

Some checks:

```
Quaternion[3, 0, 0, 0] ** Quaternion[7, 0, 0, 0]
(* Quaternion[21, 0, 0, 0] *)

QJ ** QK
(* Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0] *)

QI ** QK
(* Quaternion[0, 0, -1, 0] *)

QI ** QJ ** QK
(* Quaternion[-1, 0, 0, 0] *)
```

Here's a simplistic formatting rule. This is just for demonstration--you should make this more robust.

```
Format[Quaternion[a_, b_, c_, d_]] := a + b i + c j + d k
```

Which gives,

```
Quaternion[1, 1, 1, 1] ** Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* dispays as -8 + 4 i + 2 j + 6 k *)

Quaternion[1, 1, 1, 1] ** Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4] // FullForm
(* Quaternion[-8, 4, 2, 6] *)
```

**Note**

I'm only vaguely familiar with quaternions and non-commutative multiplication, so there may be semantic errors above. It should all be made robust and then tested.

Comment: There is also a Quaternion resource function by Wolfram staff [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Quaternion/).

Comment: Thanks! The algebra of quaternions here is only an example.  I want to define the rules for the algebra and let Mathematica do the calculations so that I don't need to define everything for the algebra.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I illustrated?

Comment: No, the quaternionic product is already done by hand and given as a function `Quaternion[
      a1 a2 - b1 b2 - c1 c2 - d1 d2, 
      a1 b2 + b1 a2 + c1 d2 - d1 c2, 
      a1 c2 - b1 d2 + c1 a2 + d1 b2, 
      a1 d2 + b1 c2 - c1 b2 + d1 a2]`. Suppose we have a different rule for the algebra, say i is the cube root of the -1. Then you have to redefine those quantities inside `Quaternion[...]`

Comment: You're going to have to define the rules somewhere.

Comment: Yes. My approach to define these rules is using the TagSet as you can see it in the first section of my code.  Once the rules are changed, all the calculations beneath will change automatically.

Comment: You already chose an answer, so this may be beating a dead horse, but you're missing the point by making a distinction without a difference. You could replace my  one line definition with a bunch of separate definitions like `Quaternion /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Quaternion[0, b1_, 0, 0], Quaternion[0, b2_, 0, 0]] := Quaternion[-b1 b2, 0, 0, 0]`. Maybe that would indeed be easier in your context. But the main point is to have an explicit representation for the elements in your algebra (i.e. `Quaternion`). This gives you a semantic representation instead of just a coincidental syntactic one.

Comment: As shown in the title, the problem is to define a new algebra. So the rules will be changed frequently and I would like the Mathematica do the calculations for me so that I can see the outcome immediately and then redefine the rules.

Comment: To get philosophical, we don't generally think of an algebra as an epi-phenomenon arising out of peculiar arithmetic rules. We usually think of an algebra as a more general/semantic conceptualization of operations. It turns out (amazingly) that simply declaring `i` to be the square root of `-1` and bravely working out the "normal" arithmetic operations gives you an algebra that is equivalent to one derived from a specific set of rules for rotating, translating, and scaling 2D vectors. But one can argue that both of those representations are just models of the "true" structure of the algebra.

Comment: "the problem is to define a new algebra". Yes, I understood that. I showed you how I would do it. I guess I'm just getting defensive at you saying that my way doesn't work. I can't see any meaningful distinction. You have your preferred way, and it's fine.

Comment: Mathematically, I am defining the operation for a group. New algebra is a result of this operation and new numbers will be found from the corresponding group. The  discovery of complex numbers is a result of demanding the number set to be closure under the operation of `Power`. Actually, we don't need a physical interpretation for the operation of a group like rotation or others. Anyway, thanks for your answer. I am new to StackExchange. I don't know whether I accept several answers since I have more than one questions in my problem.