# A variable with a^2=0

Tags: functions, built-in-symbols

I want to do something simple.

I want to define a variable such that a^2=0, so that say:

Exp(a) = 1+a

And any other function automatically f(a)=1+f'(0)a.

Is it possible to do that in Mathematica?

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do this though? `a^2 == 0` implies `a == 0` so just set it. `a^2 == 1` implies `a == 1` or `a == -1`.

Comment: a^2==0 does not imply anything. I trying to define a variable with a constraint. In principle the constraint could be anything, say a^3=a^2+1. "a" is not necessarily a complex number.

Comment: @flinty This implication holds for numbers, yes. But not for say working with first-order algebraic infinitesimals. See [DualNumber](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DualNumber/) in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this question from 2012](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/how-to-implement-dual-numbers-in-mathematica). It had a better reception that time.

Comment: [Grassman 'numbers'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) are scalars with an anticommutative multiplication rule, which automatically means they square to 0.  They are extremely important in physics, where their algebra can implement fermi statistics and the Pauli exclusion principle.  They also play a crucial part in supersymmetry algebras.

Comment: Perhaps more widely applicable, can also be used to implement [forward-mode automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers).

Comment: Sorry this got closed. Check the responses from the related 2012 thread to see if any work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is

```
1 + Exp[a] + f[Exp[b]] /. Exp[x_] -> 1 + x
```

> 2+a+f[1+b]

Edit:

---

for your comment:

```
a^3 + a^2 /. a^3 -> a^2 + 1
```

works as you wish.

---

```
f[a] /. a -> 0
```

Comment: I wish to set a^2=0.

Answer (score 0):

Another using [Full]Simplify method

```
a^2 + 1 // Simplify[#, a^2 == 0]&
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do:

```
Power[a, n_] /; n >= 2 ^:= 0
```

(using [`UpSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html))

```
a
(* a *)

a^2
(* 0 *)

Series[Exp[a], {a, 0, 10}] // Normal
(* 1 + a *)
```