# How to do automatic differentiation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algorithm

Does Mathematica have any [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) functionality or does it only support symbolic differentiation? If not, are there any packages or other third party implementations available?

---

**Edit** (J. M.)

Here is an example that might clarify how AD works. Consider the Horner method for evaluating a polynomial from its coefficients:

```
h[coeffs_?VectorQ, x_] := Module[{np1 = Length[coeffs], p, k},
   p = 0;
   Do[p = x p + coeffs[[k]], {k, np1, 1, -1}];
   p
   ]
```

An AD method should be able to "differentiate" this procedure and automatically produce this:

```
hp[coeffs_?VectorQ, x_] := Module[{np1 = Length[coeffs], p, p$, k},
       p$ = 0; p = 0;
   Do[p$ = x p$ + p;
      p = x p + coeffs[[k]], {k, np1, 1, -1}];
   p$
   ]
```

Note the use of the product rule to differentiate the line `p = x p + coeffs[[k]]`, as well as the ordering of the variable assignments in the "differentiated procedure".

There are more complicated examples, but traditionally, AD methods have dealt with routines that have been written procedurally. A challenge, then, is if AD methods can cope with more "idiomatic" *Mathematica* programs; that is, functional/rule-based algorithms. I believe that will be more difficult.

Comment: I don't believe there's any AD functionality built-in, but it looks to me that *Mathematica* is currently powerful enough that one should be able to write an AD procedure.

Comment: I made a few additions; I hope you don't mind. BTW: have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13912)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want source code transformation instead of operator overloading (which is straightforward to do in MMA, I think)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/is-there-any-automatic-differentiation-package (haven't voted to close yet since presumably we could do with a more complete answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a package, just an idea how such a package might work. You could define a custom value type `autoDiffValue` that stores a value and it's first derivative (with respect to some variable), then define arithmetic operations for that type:

```
Clear[autoDiffValue]
autoDiffValue /: autoDiffValue[a_, adx_] + autoDiffValue[b_, bdx_] := 
 autoDiffValue[a + b, adx + bdx]
autoDiffValue /: autoDiffValue[a_, adx_] * autoDiffValue[b_, bdx_] := 
 autoDiffValue[a*b, adx*b + a*bdx]
autoDiffValue /: autoDiffValue[a_, adx_] + b_ := 
 autoDiffValue[a + b, adx]
autoDiffValue /: autoDiffValue[a_, adx_]*b_ := 
 autoDiffValue[a*b, adx*b]
autoDiffValue /: autoDiffValue[a_, adx_]^b_ := 
 autoDiffValue[a^b, a^(b - 1)*adx*b]
```

Using that and your function `h`, you can then call:

```
h[{1, 2, 3}, autoDiffValue[5, 1]]
```

and get

> autoDiffValue[86, 32]

i.e. the value and the first derivative of `h[{1, 2, 3}, x]` at x=5

You could automate generating derivative definitions:

```
Clear[defineFunc]
defineFunc[fn_] := 
 autoDiffValue /: fn[autoDiffValue[a_, adx_]] = 
  autoDiffValue[fn[a], D[fn[a + x*adx], x] /. x -> 0]
defineFunc /@ {Sin, Cos, Exp};
```

(it's probably possible to extend `defineFunc` so it can create definitions for `Plus`, `Times`, ... too)

This is more or less the same technique you would use to define AD in e.g. C++ using operator overloading. It should work in principle, although a lot of work would still be needed to implement multivariable and higher derivatives and to support vector and matrix arguments (so calculations can be done with packed arrays).

Comment: So, [dual numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13926), apparently...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood the advantages of AD from your example. It would be nice to have a function that you can't differentiate properly or fast with `Derivative`.

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment. I suppose the automatic accuracy tracking is some sort of very limited built-in automatic differentiation, right? At least for combinations of real monotonically increasing functions.

```
makeDual[n_] := SetAccuracy[n, 1]
getDual[n_] := {N@n, 10^(1 - Accuracy[n])}

f[x_] := If[x > 0, Log[Sin[x]] + Tan[x]^3 - Sin[Cos[Sin[x]]]^17, x - 3]
r = 0.234;
{f[r], f'[r]} == getDual@f[makeDual[r]]
(* True *)
```