# Computing Jacobians and Hessians directly for IPOPT optimizer

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I've got a complicated expression for my constraint function $g(x)$, too complicated to let Mathematica compute the derivatives symbolically. By forcing only numeric inputs, IPOPT does (it appears) an approximation of the derivatives. But I can come up with a direct, simple expression for those derivatives in a callable function. Is there a simple not-documented option to provide my own callable function? I know there is using IPOPT directly.

Comment: This sounds like you are referring to automatic differentiation, which has been the topic of a few posts https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/is-there-any-automatic-differentiation-package https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85682/how-to-do-automatic-differentiation and AceGEN is mentioned in theses threads https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/acegen/

Comment: Not quite, since I have an approximation to the Hessian (for example) that I want to use, that is simpler than what I would get from auto diff. But I will follow the link, thanks!

Comment: Aha, I see.  If you are using `FindMinimum` does have a `"Gradient"` option that should allow you to specify your function, and `"Method"->"InteriorPoint"` appears to use IPOPTLink

Comment: Thanks...I'd also want to be able to specify (from the IPOPT docs) the Jacobian of the constraints and the Hessian of the Lagrangian function. Sounds like there is no mechanism.