# How to estimate Taylor series expansion from the function values

Tags: fitting

I have a function $y=y(x)$ which can be sampled for any $x_i\in (-0.5,0.5)$ with $\epsilon=10^{-10}$ accuracy. I can generate any number of data points $(x_i,y_i)$.
It is known that it can be expanded into the infinite Taylor series $y(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i x^i$ about $x=0$ with decreasing coefficients $c_i$. Coefficients decrease fast enough $c_0\approx 1.0$, $c_{10}\approx 0.001$. The problem is to estimate first $n$ coefficients $c_i$ as accurately as possible.

First, I truncated the Taylor expansion to a polynomial, say up to $n=10$, $y(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{10} c_i x^i$. Then I generated data sets $(x_i,y_i)$ and used the **Fit** function. However, Mathematica starts increasing higher coefficients $c_i$ to compensate for low values of $x_i$. Say, I take the point $x=0.15$, then $x^{10}\approx 10^{-8}$. Then **Fit** increases the coefficient $c_{10}$ to $10^5$ to compensate for terms of the order $10^{-3}$.

Is it possible to give higher coefficients a lower weighting in the fit to prevent them from growing? I tried to use a constrained fit like $|c_i|<0.5$ for $i=3,4,5,\ldots$ but it takes forever to converge and produces wrong results anyway.

Comment: Please include Mathematica code that people can run themselves. Semi-serious comment: If $y$ is holomorphic in a small disk around the origin, and can be sampled for small complex arguments, then one could try to use [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem).

Comment: It would be great to use Cauchy's formula but I simplified the problem.  The original function y(x) is only holomorphic in the segment 0<Arg[x]<Pi in the upper half-plane with real Taylor coefficients c_i. It has a branch cut on the real axis and the Cauchy theorem can not be used.

Comment: The original problem/code is more complicated, I will try to simplify the code to demonstrate the problem. My question is how to apply different weights to optimization parameters instead of data weighting.

Comment: Perhaps your focus is on the result more than the method and so you are maybe open to solutions not involving fitting.I am not sure if you can after posting your question but if that is the case then  you might want to include more tags than just fitting. Some people here have filters that they only see questions related to certain tags.

Comment: Is the branch cut a finite distance away from the origin ? If you want a Taylor expansion at the origin then it should be a finite distance away. If that is the case then @user293787 suggestion still seems valid as you can consider a circle with a radius smaller than the distance from the origin to the nearest singularity. You might need to try different values for the radius as there could be an optimum value. That said, the function ND might have a method that does that.

Comment: Tank's for the hint, but I thought that an accurate Taylor series coefficients are sought. If you use NIntegrate you need some interval to integrate over. This seems contradictory to the idea of Tylor series that approximates a function in the vicinity of a point.

Comment: I'm confused. If it has a Taylor series, then it is analytic in a neighborhood of the point. Are you working with say a piecewise analytic function such as `sqrt(x^2)`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*

Thought my original answer would give another view into why it's "just a problem with precision," in Silvia's words, that would make it easy to see why. I also thought it showed that approaches with `ND[]` and other local methods for estimating derivative would be unable to achieve the OP's goals.  Apparently I was wrong: Either something I wrote is incorrect or it's not easy to see. So I will add a few points.

1. Let me point a well-known phenomenon: Differentiation magnifies noise.  So inexact data will lead to increasingly inaccurate derivatives.
2. While it's true that mathematically derivatives are determined by local function values, numerically it's a bad idea to make the step size too small, since differentiation essentially magnifies the error by the reciprocal of the step size.
3. Actually for an analytic function, that is, represented by a power series, over a large domain, it can turn out to be better to increase the range of the sampling (up to a point).
4. Pseudospectral sampling, such as in my original answer, is nice and shows the point at which the maximum precision is achieved; but we can even use uniform sampling to make a good estimate of the derivative in the center of the interval.
5. If the domain is finite and the noise/round-off fixed, then there is a limit to the order of the derivative that can be accurately approximated.

For an example, I show off `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``, which has not yet shown up in an answer, on the analytic function $e^x+2 \cos x$.  I use a uniform `grid` 33 points (interpolation order 32). The scale `s` sets the interval for the sample to $[-s,s]$. The table shows the difference from the exact derivative ${d^k \over dx^k} (e^x+2 \cos x)$, $k=0,1,\dots,15$. The exact derivative is shown in the last column. Large error values are colored. One can see from the table that the error increases with the order of the derivative, but more significantly, it decreases as the scale/grid-space increases up to a point.

[image]

```
nn = 32; (* order of interpolation *)
ff[x_] := Exp[x] + 2 Cos[x];
Table[
    If[s =!= Infinity,
     grid = Range[-N@nn, nn, 2]/nn*s;
     fvals = ff[grid];
     ];
    Table[
     If[k == 0,
      (* header *)
      Row[{"s .= ", s}],
      If[s === Infinity,
       (* exact value *)
       D[ff[x], {x, k}] /. x -> 0.,
       (* error of approximation *)
       NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[k, grid, fvals, 
           DifferenceOrder -> nn - k + 1][[1 + nn/2]] -
         (D[ff[x], {x, k}] /. x -> 0.) /.
        {d_ /; Abs[d] >= 10 :> 
          Style[d, Blend[{Darker@Red, Magenta}]],
         d_ /; Abs[d] >= 1/1000 :> Style[d, Darker@Green]}
       ]
      ],
     {k, 0, 15}],
    {s, 2^Range[-2, 5]~Join~{Infinity}}] // Transpose // 
  Grid[#, Alignment -> "."] & // ScientificForm[#, 2] &
```

---

*Original answer*

I believe the growth in $c_i$ is due to the effect of noise ($\epsilon \approx 10^{-10}$). One also might consider, given $-0.5<x<0.5$, the basis functions $\phi_n(x) = (2x)^n$ instead of the power basis $x^n$, which is making the coefficients $c_i$ seem larger than their effect. The coefficients with respect to $\phi_n$ would be $c_n/2^n$.

As an example, here a Chebyshev series of a noisy function:

```
ff = Function[x, Sin[x] + Exp[2 x]];
nn = 32; (* degree of approximation *)
xx = Sin[Pi/2 Range[1. nn, -1. nn, -2.]/nn]/2;
SeedRandom[0];
noise = RandomReal[10^-10 {-1, 1}, nn + 1];
yy = ff[xx] + noise;
cc = Sqrt[2/nn] FourierDCT[yy, 1];
cc[[{-1, 1}]] /= 2;
ListPlot[RealExponent@cc, GridLines -> {{11}, None}, 
 DataRange -> {0, nn}]
```

[image]

In this example, the maximum achievable precision is obtain with degree 11. One should expect the Taylor coefficients to increase after this point.

```
(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13681/4999*)
chebeval[cof_?VectorQ, x_] := 
 Module[{m = Length[cof], j, u, v, w}, w = v = 0;
  Do[u = 2 x v - w + cof[[j]];
   w = v; v = u, {j, m, 2, -1}];
  Expand[x v - w + First[cof]]]

chebeval[cc[[;; 17]], 2 x]
Series[ff[x], {x, 0, 16}] // Normal // N

(* polynomials *)

ListPlot[RealExponent@{
   CoefficientList[chebeval[cc[[;; 17]], 2 x], x],
   CoefficientList[Series[ff[x], {x, 0, 16}] // Normal // N, x]
   },
 PlotLabel -> "Log[coefficient]", DataRange -> {0, 16}]
```

[image]

The separation starts a little earlier, at degree $10$.

Comment: Thanks! A nice answer that deserves more reading! I guess I should have given the question more thought than trivially dismissing it with "just a problem with precision".

Comment: @Silvia "A problem with precision" is an accurate and succinct summary.

Answer (score 3):

Without a minimal working example from OP, I suspect this is just a problem with insufficient precision. To demonstrate what I mean, let me use `Exp[-(x/10)]` for example.

First we define two data set with different precisions:

```
dataLP = RandomReal[10^-3, 100] // 
          Function[x, {x, Exp[-(x/10)]}//Transpose];

dataHP = RandomReal[10^-3, 100, WorkingPrecision -> 100] // 
          Function[x, {x, Exp[-(x/10)]}//Transpose];
```

The ground truth:

```
Series[Exp[-(x/10)], {x, 0, 6}] // Normal // N

(*
1. -0.1 x+0.005 x^2-0.000166667 x^3+4.16667*10^-6 x^4-8.33333*10^-8 x^5+1.38889*10^-9 x^6
*)
```

Fitting with the low precision data:

```
LinearModelFit[dataLP, x^Range[6], x]["BestFit"] // N
(*
1. -0.1 x+0.00499983 x^2+0.000594451 x^3-1.61603 x^4+1591.12 x^5-585625. x^6
*)
```

Fitting with the high precision data:

```
LinearModelFit[dataHP, x^Range[6], x]["BestFit"] // N
(*
1. -0.1 x+0.005 x^2-0.000166667 x^3+4.16667*10^-6 x^4-8.33333*10^-8 x^5+1.38882*10^-9 x^6
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series is accurate around the expansion point. Therefore it does not make sense to fit over an extended region. Rather using the difference quotient and "Limit" seems more promising.

Here is an example using the sine function:

```
<< NumericalCalculus`
f[x_] = Sin[x];
dq[n_] := Module[{x}, ND[f[x], {x, n}, 0, WorkingPrecision -> 32]];
taylor[x_, n_] := f[0] + Sum[dq[i] x^i/i!, {i, n}];
funs[x_] = Table[taylor[x, i], {i, 1, 10, 2}];
Plot[{ f[x], taylor[x, 1], taylor[x, 3], taylor[x, 7]}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Sin", "1.order", "3.order", "7.order"}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: +1. The $\epsilon=10^{-10}$ part caught my eye, I didn't notice the extended $(-0.5,0.5)$ interval.

Comment: Is something missing? `dq[n_]` does not depend on `n`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake.  At this time I also learned from userrandrnad that MMA has a ready made numerical differentiation routine and there is no need to do it ourselves. . However, one need to increase the working precision, otherwise one gets mediocre results. I fixed my example accordingly.

Comment: @DanielHuber Using the method NIntegrate gives much more precise results in this case. In fact, if I remember correctly Cauchy's Integral formula has exponential convergence with the number of function evaluations when the function has a finite non zero radius of convergence. The argument in the exponent is an increasing function of the radius of convergence of the function. For functions that are entire like Sin, if I remember correctly, the accuracy is 1/n! where n is the number of function evaluations.

Comment: Perhaps the reason why Method->NIntegrate is not the default method is that it requires complex input. That said I have not experimented much with the EulerSum method. For those reading this comment, Trefethen has a very pedagogical article showing the capabilities of the trapezoidal method with periodic boundary conditions entitled "The Exponentially Convergent
Trapezoidal Rule". One of the examples uses the Cauchy Integral formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the function ND:**

If I understand correctly you have a numerical function and you want its m first Taylor expansion coefficients. These coefficients are the r'th derivatives of the function at x=0 divided by the factorial of r. Hence, you could use the function [ND](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html) to compute numerical derivatives (you have to use Needs["NumericalCalculus`"] before but the package is already installed). Maybe you might have to use the options of that function to optimize the accuracy. I should mention that I do not remember using this function much and I do not know how accurate the methods are. With finite difference methods, if I remember correctly, higher order derivatives tend to be less precise but ND might have methods where all the coefficients would be equally as precise. In particular one of the methods of this function uses the Cauchy integral formula mentioned in the comments.

**Automatic differentiation ?**

You could also maybe use [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) but Mathematica does not have a function for that I think (Version 13). Moreover, I usually only see this method applied to obtain the first derivative. Higher order derivatives are maybe rarely looked at because automatic differentiation tends to be used in high dimensional problems and computing the Hessian there is quite costly.
That said you can find a package for Mathematica under development with a post on stack exchange [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1873/86543). I do not know if you can compute higher order  derivatives with that.

**Automatic differentiation on Python ?**

I remember my post-doc advisor telling me about Jax in Python for automatic differentiation. Pytorch's torch.autograd also does automatic differentiation if I understand correctly. Perhaps these programs only look at the first derivative.

**Shameless publicity for a free product that is not available yet**

I actually made an automatic differentiation program in Mathematica using Mathematica's neural network functions and I plan to post it on stack exchange in the future.

Comment: It would be interesting to your ad code based on neural nets. As for jax and pytorch, it is possible to nest grad to get higher order, but it is not efficient. jax also has [jet](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.experimental.jet.html), [functorch](https://pytorch.org/functorch/stable/)  has jacrev and jacfwd that can be nested.